# Automating the Title of a chart in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: macros, charts, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm not even sure I could do this in Excel, but feel reasonably confident that with enough nosing around in the VBA world I could make it happen.  But, I have switched to OpenOffice for the foreseeable future so my question:

In OpenOffice 4.0 is it possible to link the title of a chart to a spreadsheet cell? Essentially I want a nice bold Title on a chart that changes when a particular cell on the spreadsheet is updated.  This cell already controls which data is plotted on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, and with OpenOffice macros it is quite easy. Step-by-Step:

**Enabling macros**

Go to the *Tools > Options* menu and click on the *Security* section under *OpenOffice.org*. Once there, click the *Macro Security* button. Now on the *Security Level* Tab, make sure that your settings will allow you to run Macros.

My settings are on low because I'm the author of all the macros I run, if you are not sure that this will be your case you might want to use a higher setting.

**Note:** Be careful, if you are unlucky or live in the 90's an evil macro can cause serious damage!

---

**Creating a new macro**

Now that you can run them, you must create a new macro. OpenOffice accepts a wide range of languages including Python, but since you mentioned VBA in your question I'll use OO's version of it here.

Go to Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > OpenOffice.org Basic, and once there add a new module under your file's tree. Give it a meaningful name.

[image: New module]

---

**The actual macro**

Once you create a new module the editor screen will pop up, write this code below:

```
' Set the title of the first Chart to the contents of C1
Sub SetTitle
    ' Get active sheet
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

    ' Get the cell containing the chart title, in this case C1
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("C1")
    oCharts = oSheet.getCharts() 

    ' Get the chart with index 0, which is the first chart created
    ' to get the second you would use 1, the third 2 and so on...
    oChart = oCharts.getByIndex(0)


    oChartDoc = oChart.getEmbeddedObject()

    'Change title
    oChartDoc.getTitle().String = oCell.getString() 
End Sub
```

To test it, just create a chart, put something as a title on the cell C1 and run the macro. You can run the macro in many ways, for test purposes just use the Run button on the same window that you used to create the module. This is the expected result:

[image: Expected results]

---

**Further improving the macro**

The macro have some issues as it is right now, such as:

- Having to re-run the macro every time you want the title updated.

This is easily fixed. There are many ways to automatize the macro execution, the one I'm most familiar with consists on making it run on a loop in conjunction with a delay of, say, 5 seconds and making it start as soon as the file loads.

```
Sub Main
    Do While True
        SetTitle()
        Wait(5000)
    Loop
End Sub
```

And from now on you should call the Main sub instead of the SetTitle.

To make the macro run at start-up go to *Tools > Customize* on the *Events* tab and select *Open Document* from the list then click on the *Macro* button. On the dialog to select the macro, pick *Main*. Now close the document, reopen it, and voila!

- Having to address the chart by its index.

You can use the chart name instead (Right Click the chart > Name) like this:

```
oChart = oCharts.getByName("Chart Name")
```

---

**Further reading**

- I based this macro on code from [this PDF by Jacek Wiślicki](http://jacenty.kis.p.lodz.pl/i2cs/openoffice/lab_05b.pdf).
- [This piece of official reference](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Charts) explains more about chart structure, its fields and services.
- [This post on the official forums](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=55115) seems to have some very relevant information.
- [A guide on different ways to run a macro](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/How_to_run_a_macro)
- [A great introduction to macro programming](http://www.openoffice.org/documentation/manuals/oooauthors/macros_intro_v1.pdf)