# Automating the Title of a chart in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: vba, libreoffice

I have found the below code (changed to my needs) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834446/automating-the-title-of-a-chart-in-openoffice-calc)

I try to change the titles of many charts automatically, using macro in libre calc 7.3.0.

I Know which cells contain the titles and I want them to add them to charts.
How can I make this VBA vcode to work?

```
Const SCells = "L8, T8, AA8"

' Set the title of the first Chart to the contents of C1
Sub SetTitle
    ' Get active sheet
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    
    aCells = Split(SCells,",")
    
    for i = uBound(aCells) to 0 step -1
        
    ' Get the cell containing the chart title, in this case C1
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(aCells(i))
   
    oCharts = oSheet.getCharts() 
    ' Get the chart with index 0, which is the first chart created
    ' to get the second you would use 1, the third 2 and so on...
    oChart = oCharts.getByIndex(i)

    oChartDoc = oChart.getEmbeddedObject()

    'Change title
    oChartDoc.getTitle().String = oCell.getString() 

    next i
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrongly? I had spaces in Const SCells content:
"L11, T11, E11" which was wrong.

I checked the content of aCells using [xraytool](https://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) and I found that the content was parsed as 1) "L11", 2) " T11" and 3) " E11", with spaces.

So you can change automatically the title of your charts in a librecalc sheet using that vba code:

> ```
> ' NOTE: NO SPACES OR OTHER CHARACTERS
> Const SCells = "L11,T11,E11"
>
>
> Sub SetTitle
>
>     ' Get active sheet
>     oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
>     
>     ' Split SCells content by "," 
>     ' see Print aCells for corrent content
>     aCells = Split(SCells,",")
>        
>                
>         'enumarate by "1" point increment
>     for i  = uBound(aCells) to 0 step -1
>     
>       ' using aCells Content
>       oCell  = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(aCells(i))
>
>       oCharts = oSheet.getCharts() 
>       ' Get the chart with index 0, which is the first chart created
>       ' to get the second you would use 1, the third 2 and so on...
>       oChart = oCharts.getByIndex(i)
>
>       oChartDoc = oChart.getEmbeddedObject()
>
>       'Change title
>       oChartDoc.getTitle().String = oCell.getString() 
>
>       ' xray oChart.Name
>
>     next i
>     
>  End Sub
> ```